# Convert named vector to list in R

Tags: r, vector

Suppose I have the following named numeric vector:

```
a <- 1:8
names(a) <- rep(c('I', 'II'), each = 4)
```

How can I convert this vector to a list of length 2 (shown below)?

```
a.list
# $I
# [1] 1 2 3 4
# $II
# [1] 5 6 7 8
```

Note that `as.list(a)` is not what I'm looking for.
My very unsatisfying (and slow for large vectors) solution is:

```
names.uniq <- unique(names(a))
a.list <- setNames(vector('list', length(names.uniq)), names.uniq)
for(i in 1:length(names.uniq)) {
  names.i <- names.uniq[i]
  a.i <- a[names(a)==names.i]
  a.list[[names.i]] <- unname(a.i)
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help,
Devin

Comment: Maybe `split(a, names(a))`. Then `unname` the list's vectors.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, you can use `split` to create a list.

```
a.list <- split(a, names(a))
a.list <- lapply(a.list, unname)
```

A one-liner would be

```
a.list <- lapply(split(a, names(a)), unname)
#$I
#[1] 1 2 3 4
#
#$II
#[1] 5 6 7 8
```

**EDIT.**
Then, thelatemail posted a simplification of this in his comment. I've timed it using Devin King's way and it's not only simpler it's also 25% faster.

```
a.list <- split(unname(a),names(a))
```

Comment: No need for 2 lapply loops - `split(unname(a),names(a))` will do it.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest looking at packages that excel at working with aggregating large amounts of data, like the `data.table` package. With `data.table`, you could do:

```
a <- 1:5e7
names(a) <- c(rep('I',1e7), rep('II',1e7), rep('III',1e7),
              rep('IV',1e7), rep('V',1e7))

library(data.table)
temp <- data.table(names(a), a)[, list(V2 = list(a)), V1]
a.list <- setNames(temp[["V2"]], temp[["V1"]])
```

Here are some functions to test the various options out with:

```
myFun <- function(invec) {
  x <- data.table(names(invec), invec)[, list(V2 = list(invec)), V1]
  setNames(x[["V2"]], x[["V1"]])
}

rui1 <- function(invec) {
  a.list <- split(invec, names(invec))
  lapply(a.list, unname)
}

rui2 <- function(invec) {
  split(unname(invec), names(invec))
}

op <- function(invec) {
  names.uniq <- unique(names(invec))
  a.list <- setNames(vector('list', length(names.uniq)), names.uniq)
  for(i in 1:length(names.uniq)) {
    names.i <- names.uniq[i]
    a.i <- a[names(invec) == names.i]
    a.list[[names.i]] <- unname(a.i)
  }
  a.list
}
```

And the results of microbenchmark on 10 replications:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(myFun(a), rui1(a), rui2(a), op(a), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
#  myFun(a)  698.1553  768.6802  932.6525  934.6666 1056.558 1168.889    10
#   rui1(a) 2967.4927 3097.6168 3199.9378 3185.1826 3319.453 3413.185    10
#   rui2(a) 2152.0307 2285.4515 2372.9896 2362.7783 2426.821 2643.033    10
#     op(a) 2672.4703 2872.5585 2896.7779 2901.7979 2971.782 3039.663    10
```

Also, note that in testing the different solutions, you might want to consider other scenarios, for instance, cases where you expect to have lots of different names. In that case, your `for` loop slows down significantly. Try, for example, the above functions with the following data:

```
set.seed(1)
b <- sample(100, 5e7, TRUE)
names(b) <- sample(c(letters, LETTERS, 1:100), 5e7, TRUE)
```

Comment: Wow, your function using data.table package is lightning fast! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Testing Rui Barradas' solution vs my original solution on a larger vector

```
  a <- 1:5e7
  names(a) <- c(rep('I',1e7), rep('II',1e7), rep('III',1e7), rep('IV',1e7), rep('V',1e7))
```

Rui's

```
st1 <- Sys.time()
 a.list <- split(a, names(a))
 a.list <- lapply(a.list, unname)
Sys.time() - st1
Time difference of 2.560906 secs
```

Mine

```
st1 <- Sys.time()
names.uniq <- unique(names(a))
a.list <- setNames(vector('list', length(names.uniq)), names.uniq)
for(i in 1:length(names.uniq)) {
names.i <- names.uniq[i]
  a.i <- a[names(a)==names.i]
  a.list[[names.i]] <- unname(a.i)
}
Sys.time() - st1
Time difference of 2.712066 secs
```

thelatemail's

```
st1 <- Sys.time()
  a.list <- split(unname(a),names(a))
Sys.time() - st1
Time difference of 1.62851 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle also unnamed vectors, use then:

```
vec_to_list <- function(vec) {
  if (is.null(names(vec))) names(vec) <- 1:length(vec)
  split(unname(vec), names(vec))
}
```